# Get element's top property from its inline css

Tags: jquery

I have the following element with its inline css:

```
<div class="collection" style="top: -482px;"></div>
```

How can I get the `top` value that is set with inline css?

I know of `offset` but that returns the coordinates relative to the document as far as I know, what I need is the element's specified top position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an element's CSS property, use the jQuery method `.css()`. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1gveen0b/) to demonstrate its use.

Answer (score 1):

A nother aproach:

```
  var styles = $('.collection').attr('style').split(';');
  alert(styles[0]);
```

I'm creating an array of the inline styles and alert the first one.

UPDATE:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stefan_wave/meLvj3Lm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Var x=$(".collection").position();
  alert("Top: " + x.top + " Left: " + x.left);

This will give exact position values.